# Contar caracteres sem espaços vazios

Tags: c++, string

Tenho que contar a quantidade de caracteres de uma string, porém quando tem espaço vazio ele é contado como caractere. Como consigo retirar esses espaços vazios? Alguma dica?

Comment: Olá Felipe. Poste para nós o que você já tem pronto, fica mais fácil adaptar seu exemplo do que partir do zero.

Comment: Dica, pesquise no Google. Cade seu código para que possamos ver seu erro? É importante postar código para ele ser analisado. Agora se não tem código Search in Google.

Answer (score 2):

Alternativamente você poderia usar uma função em que toda a string fosse percorrida e o [`isspace`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isspace/) fosse utilizado para restringir a contagem de caracteres que estivessem em branco:

```
#include <ctype.h>

using namespace std;

int contarCaracteres(const string& str)
{
    int contador = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < str.size(); ++i) 
    {
        if (!isspace(str[i]))
            ++contador;
    }

    return contador;
}
```

Obs: o `isspace` considera que um caractere está em branco nos seguintes casos:

- ' '
- '\t'
- '\n'
- '\v'
- '\f'
- '\r'

Comment: Podia ser `const std::string& str` no parâmetro da função para evitar uma cópia.

Comment: Ah é verdade, como essa aplicação se limita a somente fazer essa contagem é interessante manter a boa prática de passar argumentos de classes usando referências e não diretamente por valor. Obrigado pelo lembrete @LucasNunes (:

Answer (score 1):

Para fazer isso você pode usar a função [`std::erase`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/erase/).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str = "Stack Overflow em Portugues";
    str.erase(remove(str.begin(),str.end(),' '),str.end());
    cout << str << endl;
    cout << "Lenght  " << str.length() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

O resultado será:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Se seu objetivo é apenas contar os elementos diferentes de espaço em branco, você deve dar uma olhada na função [`std::count_if`](http://pt.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) da biblioteca padrão de algoritmos ( `<algorithm>` ).

Com esta função é possível contar quantos elementos de um intervalo obedecem a um predicado. Logo, basta utilizar como predicado para [`std::count_if`](http://pt.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) uma função que retorne `true` quando o caractere não for um espaço em branco e `false` quando for. Para tal objetivo podemos utilizar a negação da função [`std::isspace`](http://pt.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isspace).

```
int main() {
    auto s = std::string{ "25 caracteres sem os espacos." };
    auto n = std::count_if( std::begin( s ), std::end( s ),
                            [](char c){ return !std::isspace( c ); } );

    std::cout << "String: \"" << s << "\"\n";
    std::cout << "Quantidade de caracteres: " << s.size( ) << "\n";
    std::cout << "Quantidade de caracteres nao brancos: " << n << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Segue um exemplo rodando da solução proposta: http://ideone.com/Wwpl5I